# How to find ruby subdirectory in pc?

Tags: ruby, windows, cmd, path, subdirectory

I can't seem to use "irb" from anywhere in my command prompt. Is there a way to find it in the sub directory or change it so that i can use the irb command prompt from any path so that i can run ruby files? Or do I just have to find the ruby file location and run it by typing "irb ruby *nameoffile" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an entry to *ruby/bin* to the **PATH** environment variable.

Then, run the irb with this option to include the current folder (and the ruby files you want to include)

```
irb -I .
```

now you can require and load your local ruby files

Comment: are you telling me to make a folder called "PATH" inside the ruby22/bin ?
I don't know what you mean by path environment variable. @ThomasHaratyk

Comment: I created a folder called ruby in ruby22/bin/ruby...went there in the command prompt, then typed "irb -I" and nothing happened. Do I type the "." too?

Comment: Well i found the interactive ruby command prompt, so I guess that'll do for now, however I haven't found out how to run a script on it yet. will do soon. Thanks :)